# following-sibling in chrome 90 gives all the siblings element while following-siblings return nothing

Tags: xpath, selenium-chromedriver

```
<tr>
 <td>
  <div>1.1</div>
 </td>
 <td>
  <div>Astate</div>
 </td>
 <td>
  <div> Giku </div>
 </td>
 </tr>
```

when i try this XPath

```
//div[contains(text(),'1.1')]/ancestor::td/following-sibling::td
```

it return me all the td inside it...ideally it should return td having  just the Astate one which i am expecting  .Also following-siblings doesn't work which is expected to return all td values actually..

Just a  slight info  table data is in horizontal format
1.1 Astate Giku 10

how do i fetch just Astate td here??

Chrome: version: 90

Answer (score 1):

`following-sibling` returns all the following siblings. Use `[1]` if you're only interested in the first one.

```
//div[contains(text(),'1.1')]/ancestor::td/following-sibling::td[1]
```

You can also simplify the expression by adding the `td` into the predicate instead of following it and returning back to ancestors:

```
//tr/td[div[contains(text(),'1.1')]]/following-sibling::td[1]
```

or even

```
//tr/td[contains(div,'1.1')]/following-sibling::td[1]
```

The `[1]` is still needed.

Comment: Doesn't the /ancestor::td/ path element in the OP's XPath mean that their following-sibling::td element is in fact requesting siblings of the <td> (as the OP intended), not siblings of the <div>?

Comment: @ConradAlbrecht: You are right, adding `[1]` to their query works, too. Updated.